# Enumerating boolean template parameters in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to determine how to take in a boolean template parameter pack

```
template<bool...B> struct BoolPack{};
```

and construct from it an integer parameter pack where the values indicate the enumeration of the `true` elements in `BoolPack`. The enumeration could be contained like this:

```
template<size_t...I> struct IntegerSequence{};
```

The function should take in a `BoolPack<B...>` and return an `IntegerSequence<I...>`;

```
template<bool...B>
constexpr auto enumerate( const BoolPack<B...>& b ) {
  // Combination of cumulative sum and mask?
  return IntegerSequence<???>();
}
```

For example, if the input would be

```
BoolPack<true,false,true,false,true> b;
```

The function should return

```
IntegerSequence<1,0,2,0,3> e();
```

My best guess on how to implement this would be to compute a partial sum
where the the kth template parameter is

```
K = K-1 + static_cast<size_t>(get<K>(make_tuple<B...>));
```

I'm not sure if this is the way to do it. Is there not a more direct approach that doesn't require making tuples for example? Applying the recursion should result in

```
IntegerSequence<1,1,2,2,3> s();
```

And then to multiply this componentwise with the elements of the original `BoolPack`. Is this the way to go, or can I do this without tuples?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no auto return type without a trailing return type in c++11 (`constexpr auto enumerate( const BoolPack<B...>& b ) /*no trailing return type (-> something)*/ {`). Are you sure you need c++11 compliant code? C++14 relaxes constexpr function rules and it would be much easier to accomplish what you want there...

Comment: Apologies, I meant to write C++14 in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you think to implement

```
template<bool...B>
constexpr auto enumerate( const BoolPack<B...>& b ) {
  // Combination of cumulative sum and mask?
  return IntegerSequence<???>();
}
```

can't work because C++ is a strong typed language, so the returned type can't depend from sums obtained from code that can be executed compile time.

I know that the values are known at compile time, so the values can be computed compile-time; but the best way that I see pass through a specific type traits.

By example (sorry: renamed `IntegerSequence` as `IndexSequence` to be more near to the C++14 `std::index_sequence`)

```
template <std::size_t, typename, std::size_t ...>
struct BoolIndexer
 { };

template <std::size_t N, bool ... Bs, std::size_t ... Is>
struct BoolIndexer<N, BoolPack<true, Bs...>, Is...>
   : public BoolIndexer<N+1U, BoolPack<Bs...>, Is..., N>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, bool ... Bs, std::size_t ... Is>
struct BoolIndexer<N, BoolPack<false, Bs...>, Is...>
   : public BoolIndexer<N, BoolPack<Bs...>, Is..., 0U>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct BoolIndexer<N, BoolPack<>, Is...>
 { using type = IndexSequence<Is...>; };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <bool ... B>
struct BoolPack
 { };

template<size_t...I>
struct IndexSequence
 { };

template <std::size_t, typename, std::size_t ...>
struct BoolIndexer
 { };

template <std::size_t N, bool ... Bs, std::size_t ... Is>
struct BoolIndexer<N, BoolPack<true, Bs...>, Is...>
   : public BoolIndexer<N+1U, BoolPack<Bs...>, Is..., N>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, bool ... Bs, std::size_t ... Is>
struct BoolIndexer<N, BoolPack<false, Bs...>, Is...>
   : public BoolIndexer<N, BoolPack<Bs...>, Is..., 0U>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct BoolIndexer<N, BoolPack<>, Is...>
 { using type = IndexSequence<Is...>; };



int main ()
 {
   using type1 = BoolPack<true,false,true,false,true>;
   using type2 = typename BoolIndexer<1U, type1>::type;

   static_assert( std::is_same<type2, IndexSequence<1,0,2,0,3>>{}, "!" );
 }
```

If you really need a function to get the conversion, using the `BoolIndexer` type traits you can write it simply as follows

```
template <bool ... Bs>
constexpr auto getIndexSequence (BoolPack<Bs...> const &)
   -> typename BoolIndexer<1U, BoolPack<Bs...>>::type
 { return {}; }
```

and call it in this way

```
auto is = getIndexSequence(BoolPack<true,false,true,false,true>{});
```

Comment: This is a nice approach. I am currently attempting to generalize it to the case where the IndexType struct could have arbitrary integral type. I will post it when I have ironed out the kinks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution pass through the creation of a `constexpr` function

```
template <bool ... Bs>
constexpr std::size_t getNumTrue (BoolPack<Bs...> const &, std::size_t top)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   std::size_t  cnt = -1;
   std::size_t  ret { 0 };

   (void)unused { 0, (++cnt <= top ? ret += Bs : ret, 0)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

that can be called to set the template values for `IndexSequence`; unfortunately the following example use `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` that are C++14 (starting from) features

```
template <bool ... Bs, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto gisH (BoolPack<Bs...> const &,
                     std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
   -> IndexSequence<(Bs ? getNumTrue(BoolPack<Bs...>{}, Is) : 0U)...>
 { return {}; }

template <bool ... Bs>
constexpr auto getIndexSequence (BoolPack<Bs...> const & bp)
 { return gisH(bp, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Bs)>{}); }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <bool ... B>
struct BoolPack
 { };

template <std::size_t...I>
struct IndexSequence
 { };

template <bool ... Bs>
constexpr std::size_t getNumTrue (BoolPack<Bs...> const &, std::size_t top)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   std::size_t  cnt = -1;
   std::size_t  ret { 0 };

   (void)unused { 0, (++cnt <= top ? ret += Bs : ret, 0)... };

   return ret;
 }

template <bool ... Bs, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto gisH (BoolPack<Bs...> const &,
                     std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
   -> IndexSequence<(Bs ? getNumTrue(BoolPack<Bs...>{}, Is) : 0U)...>
 { return {}; }

template <bool ... Bs>
constexpr auto getIndexSequence (BoolPack<Bs...> const & bp)
 { return gisH(bp, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Bs)>{}); }

int main()
 {
   using typeBP = BoolPack<true,false,true,false,true>;

   auto is = getIndexSequence(typeBP{});

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(is),
                               IndexSequence<1,0,2,0,3>>{}, "!" );
 }
```